# How to resolve "XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record" error?

Tags: python

I'm getting the following error in my code, and I'm not sure how to fix it. I'm trying to write a function that reads a list of xlsx files into individual pandas DataFrames then concatenates them into a single DataFrame.

It was working originally, but now I'm getting this XLRD Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XLRDError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-91bc654495ef> in <module>
     11 
     12 # Returns a single combined dataframe
---> 13 stacked_df = excel_to_dataframe(validation_list, BASEDIR)

<ipython-input-123-91bc654495ef> in excel_to_dataframe(list, file_path)
      5     data = []
      6     for i in list:
----> 7         df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(file_path, i), index_col=None)
      8         data.append(df)
      9     # Concatanates the list of validation dataframes

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    186                 else:
    187                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 188             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    189         return wrapper
    190     return _deprecate_kwarg

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    186                 else:
    187                     kwargs[new_arg_name] = new_arg_value
--> 188             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    189         return wrapper
    190     return _deprecate_kwarg

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, parse_cols, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skip_footer, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols, **kwds)
    348 
    349     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
--> 350         io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
    351 
    352     return io.parse(

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in __init__(self, io, engine)
    651         self._io = _stringify_path(io)
    652 
--> 653         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
    654 
    655     def __fspath__(self):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    422             self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=data)
    423         elif isinstance(filepath_or_buffer, compat.string_types):
--> 424             self.book = xlrd.open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
    425         else:
    426             raise ValueError('Must explicitly set engine if not passing in'

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    155         formatting_info=formatting_info,
    156         on_demand=on_demand,
--> 157         ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
    158     )
    159     return bk

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py in open_workbook_xls(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
     90         t1 = perf_counter()
     91         bk.load_time_stage_1 = t1 - t0
---> 92         biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
     93         if not biff_version:
     94             raise XLRDError("Can't determine file's BIFF version")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py in getbof(self, rqd_stream)
   1276             bof_error('Expected BOF record; met end of file')
   1277         if opcode not in bofcodes:
-> 1278             bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
   1279         length = self.get2bytes()
   1280         if length == MY_EOF:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\book.py in bof_error(msg)
   1270 
   1271         def bof_error(msg):
-> 1272             raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
   1273         savpos = self._position
   1274         opcode = self.get2bytes()

XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\rJulian '
```

Here are my base and log directories:

```
DATE_NOW = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
BASEDIR = Path(r'\\company.Net\NDrive\Project\50813\NJ1\Task 3 Db-Template-Tools Dev\UPL\upl_workbooks\2020_workbooks\Uploaded to S3\log_csv files\NEW_REPROCESSED_NF_OP')
LOGDIR = BASEDIR / 'validation_summary_output'
LOGNAME = BASEDIR / LOGDIR / f"final_validation_output_{DATE_NOW}.xlsx"
```

And here is the code that reads the xlsx files into DataFrames:

```
def excel_to_dataframe(list, file_path):
    """
    The function reads the list of xlsx files into individual dataframes then combines them into a single dataframe.
    """
    data = []
    for i in list:
        df = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(file_path, i), index_col=None)
        data.append(df)
    # Concatanates the list of validation dataframes
    return pd.concat(data, sort=True)

# Returns a single combined dataframe 
stacked_df = excel_to_dataframe(validation_list, pathlib.Path(BASEDIR))
```

How do I fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: The code provided doesn't read any files, it merely gets a list of filenames and puts them in a list. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: My apologies Michael, I put the wrong code into the question. The code I put in now is what's giving me the error. The last code black creates a list of files and the code above searches for those files in the list and appends them to a DataFrame.

Comment: as don't have access to your excel, cant reproduce. the possibility can be due to excel format/version. the read_excel is assuming the file as "xlrd" (old version excel), you can try to change the engine. `pd.read_excel(os.path.join(file_path, i), engine='openpyxl', index_col=None)` and this supports new excel versions. [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

Comment: I noticed when I print the `validation_list` the last file in the list is a temporary file called '~$2020_NF_R1_ME_01_VALIDATIONS.xlsx'. Could removing this temp file get rid of the error?